# Sybase Infomaker -- Interdependent Menus, How do I link them?

Tags: sql-server, drop-down-menu, menu, sybase, infomaker

The infomaker application connects to the SQL Server database. 
This is where the data comes from (there is a table lets call it LT_DATA).

LT_DATA has the following

```
ID   PROGRAM         Curriculum
1    Elementary      Europe
2    Elementary      Asia
3    Elementary      Africa
4    Secondary       Australia
5    Secondary       Europe
```

The infomaker has two menus.

The user selects Program in one menu and prior to hitting save the user will select a second menu. The second menu needs to be filtered by the first. So if the user selects Secondary Program in the drop down menu the second one should only show Australia and Europe.

[image]

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL Server?

Comment: The database/infomaker lives on sql server, and that is where the data comes from. It's always related to sql server (sometimes syntax of how things can/should be done could be related to that too).

Comment: But you've also tagged Sybase, a totally different RDBMS?

Comment: Sybase is the company who built infomaker and use the SQL Server and other types of databases.

Comment: You say "menu" but it seems your question is about DDDWs. It's been a long time since I used Powerbuilder (and IM is a scaled-down version of that IIRC) but we typically used a DDDW that contained all the possible values and simply filtered it based on the currently selected value in the first DDDW.

Comment: And I should note that it has been a looooong time since Sybase sold off Powerbuilder/Informaker.

Comment: @SMor yes i'm looking to build two DDDW in infomaker (powerbuilder). Yes I want to do exactly what you are saying, but one datawindow will filter down the other (and this isn't on a save simply on select from one menu to the next). Do you have notes/advice or guidance how you accomplished it. Thank you

Comment: There is an event a value is selected in a DDDW. You grab the selected value there and then do whatever you want with it. IIRC there are actually 2 events - selectionchanging and selectionchanged - the former for validating and rejecting if needed and the latter for any "after" actions). In this case, you simply filter the other DDDW using that value. Obviously the query that populates the second DDDW must include the column that you need for filtering even if you don't display it. Re-retrieving is also an expensive but simpler option.